Server Can't Be Found On Some Devices
I have deployed my webapp to a server and I checked it and it is working fine. however on some iOS devices it doesn't open 'Safari Cannot open the page because the server can't be found'. this only happens when the phone is using Cellular Data. when it is connected to a Wi-Fi it works.
What could be the reason?
Thank you.

Could be a lot of reasons.... but without more information, we can't really help you.  It might be as simple as just waiting for DNS propagation, if you've recently changed what DNS servers your domain uses.

Sounds like an issue with DNS propagation not yet done to all name servers.

I waited for some time and now it works.
I think it was DNS propagation issue.
